# im trying to fix an error on my code when adding number to another number in a file

Tags: list, file, split, addition, python-3.3

I have a file like this:

```
  RubyWilson,20,174.0,female,23.45,1562.41,**367**
```

I'm trying to add a number to the last number in the file
like this:

```
  number = 300

  RubyWilson,20,174.0,female,23.45,1562.41,**667**
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
  name = input("name")
  FitnessFile = open((name + "fitness file.csv") , "r")
  myVar = FitnessFile.read()
  FitnessFile.close()
  myList = myVar.split(",")
  number = int(input("enter number"))
  str(myList[6])) = int(myList[6]) + (number)

  FitnessFile = open((name + "fitness file.csv") , "w")
  addList = ",".join(myList)
  FitnessFile.write(addList)
  FitnessFile.close()
```

When I run it, it says can't assign function call
on line 6.

How do I fix this?

Comment: so how do i do it then

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to a function call. Why are you parsing myList[6] to string  (str(myList[6]))? 

Try:
myList[6] = int(myList[6]) + (number)

Instead of :
str(myList[6]) = int(myList[6]) + (number)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to replace

```
str(myList[6])) = int(myList[6]) + (number)
```

which, by the way, isn't even syntactically valid, with

```
myList[6] = str(int(myList[6]) + (number))
```

However, none of this takes care of the asterisks. Do they actually appear in your data?